# Idiom for new-employee training period

Tags: single-word-requests, idioms, phrase-requests

There’s a certain amount of time that organizations apply to new employees who are undergoing training.  What’s the idiom? I’ve heard *spin-up* or *train-up* time, but neither of those two is clicking as correct.

The period of time is variable. The nature of the period is training, like learning the company handbook, policies, or IT system.

Comment: "Break in", perhaps?  "Get up to speed"?

Comment: Onboarding? Orientation? Probation? You'll need to be more specific as to the length and nature of the introductory period.

Comment: @choster, the period of time is variable.  The nature of the period is training, e.g. learning the company's handbook, policies, or IT system.  I settled for "indoctrination" yesterday, but I am still unhappy with the word.  Indoctrination is too strong and parallels mild brainwashing.

Comment: I like "orientation" best. Without context, it kinda implies "short" -- like a day at most -- but it's a flexible word.

Comment: Nesting period.....Isn't it.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At every company I've worked at, the process of hiring and preparing an employee for the job is referred to as employee onboarding.

Comment: //shudder and //ew.

Answer (score 0):

Probie can be used if a new employee is on probation.

http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/probie

> noun, Informal.
>   1.
>   a probationer, especially a firefighter who has recently joined a department.